# Compact relay banks

Tags: audio, relay, low-power, analog-switch, latching-relay

I'd like to switch about 20-30 audio signals. By "audio", I mean non-DC that is low-voltage (<5V peak) and low-current (<50mA peak).

I'd like this switching to occupy the smallest possible PCB real-estate, ideally about an inch squared.

Since it's an audio application, the distortion should be minimal (like-a-relay minimal)

Nice to have: I intend to control the switches using some micro-controller (think of a PIC or an Arduino) and for the best power consumption, I'd like this controller to drive the switches only to change state, not to maintain it. As a result the switches need to be of latching type.

Can you suggest a solution or product that would fit this bill?

Comment: Audio matrix switches surely exist as integrated circuits. See if you can get a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audio bus switches. Ics in dip or ssop or smaller, and a microcontroller to control them. Or ones where you can use simple momentary switches or gang switches. Mechanical relays are noisy and power-hungry compared to digital/analog switching.

If you're dead set on relays, then the keywords you are looking for are "latching" or "set/unset" for the feature where you don't have to keep the coil energized. And the form factor would be "miniature" or "sub miniature" relays.

Comment: A purpose-made IC will also have the advantage of guaranteed on-state resistance flatness across all channels.

Comment: The ICs I've looked at have 0-5V, that's not great for audio. I guess I need to set the audio `GND` to `Vcc/2`

Comment: @Eric plenty of them have -5 to +5 operation, negative rail connections, etc.